# Change Background with .css and jCarousel

Tags: css, ajax, dynamic, background, jcarousel

I try do dynamic gallery with jCarousel and Ajax.
My thumbs are loading from '.txt' file. 
I try do something like this: If click the thumb body background are change <--- this action for all thumbs but different backgrounds...
But if I try add dynamic url for differents files, it isin't work, If I change + url + for accurate path it work, all picture loaded this same picture from the path - it is understandable ....

### below my code

```
  function mycarousel_getItemHTML(url)
{
    return '<img src="' + url + '" width="200" height="75" alt="" border="0" class="newbg" />';
};


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 2,
        itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback
    });

    $('.newbg').live("click", function(){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
    });
});
```

anybody has an idea as change this code for correct effects...?

Comment: what is jquery version do you use ? i suggest use latest version...

Answer (score 0):

I add something like this:

```
$('.newbg').livequery("click", function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
    };
       img.src = url;                         
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
    });
```

And it's work correct, thank...

Question can be close...